# New server - all log files archived after first night

Tags: ubuntu, server-setup

I recently set up two virtual servers running Ubuntu 16.04. After my basic configuration of the servers (ufw, fail2ban, sshd config) I disconnected from the servers.

The next day I reconnected via SSH. To check if the servers were "hacked" in the meantime I ran

`$ last`

And I got a little heart attack: The command did not show a single entry although I did some "logging-in" the day before. So I prematurely assumed that someone hacked into my servers and cleared the wtmp log files to obfuscate his intrusion.

After I had a deeper look I found out that the file `wtmp.1` exists in my `/var/log/` directory. So I ran

`$ last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`

And the output seemed to be fine - no unknown logins. Now my question is:

Why did my two servers "archive" all log files (`wtmp.1`, `auth.log.1`, ...) after just a half day. Although my `/etc/logrotate` is pretty basic:

```
su root syslog

rotate 4

create

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

Is there a chance I got hacked - or how can this behaviour be explained??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was your time set correctly?  Was your server set to use NTP or something to get correct time?

Comment: I did not set the time. NTP is not set up. However the `date` returns the right date and time.